# Hide CSS Grid element if empty

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to hide the Grid element if it is empty with the `:empty` pseudo-class.

CSS

```
.o-grid {
    display: grid;
}

.o-grid--half {
    width: 50%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1,minmax(0,1fr));
}

.o-grid:empty { display: none; }
```

Normal element with content.

```
<div class="o-grid o-grid--half">
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Some Content</div>
</div>
```

But, if the element has no content, the Grid element space is preserved, and the browser will keep a space for it, and I want to disable this.

```
<div class="o-grid o-grid--half">

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: No. Grid areas are not elements and so cannot be selected or styled by css

Comment: I don't quite understand because the div (which happens to have display grid normally and then is given display: none if it empty) does 'disappear' if it is empty, no space is left for it. Are you meaning if one of the items in the grid is empty the item next to it should ake up the space or something? Perhaps if you put up a runnable snippet we'd be able to help more. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `:has()` selector

```css
.o-grid {
    display: grid;
}

.o-grid--half {
    width: 50%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1,minmax(0,1fr));
}

.o-grid:not(:has(*)) { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="o-grid o-grid--half">
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Some Content</div>
</div>

<div class="o-grid o-grid--half">

</div>
```